# Ошибка связанная с MySQl. Не могу нормально загрузить данные в БД

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных

В общем, у меня есть код MySQL который добавляет в базу данных id пользователя и его username. но у меня выходит наинеприятнейшая ошибка : `pymysql.err.InterfaceError: (0, '')`

Код MySQl:

```
import pymysql

try:
    connection = pymysql.connect(
        host = "127.0.0.1",
        port=3306,
        user = "root",
        password = "root",
        database = "mysql_db",
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

    print("succerssfully conected...")
    print("#" * 20)

    try:
        def add_inform_user(user_id, user_name):
            infor_user = "INSERT INTO `user` (user_id, username) VALUES (%s, %s);"
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                print(user_id, user_name)
                cursor.execute(infor_user, (user_id, user_name))
                connection.commit()
                print("Данные добавились...")


        def add_lang_user(language):
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                pass

    finally:
        connection.close()


except Exception as ex:
    print("Connection refused...")
    print(ex)
```

Импорт нужных данных с помощью функции работает нормально, ошибка возникает когда код доходит именно до этой момента: `connection.commit()`

Помогите начинающему программисту, буду очень благодарен если еще и все поясните! :)

Comment: Как и в [другом (ныне удалённом) вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1540865), показанный здесь код ничего не делает, только подключается к БД и затем сразу отключается, в таком виде рассматривать его нет смысла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убрал вложенный try: finaly: и все магическим образом заработало, но все же хотелось бы узнать почему исключение вызывало такую ошибку.

Comment: Прятать **определения** функций в `try`/`finally` - ну очень интересное решение ))  Чтобы узнать, какое там было исключение, нужно было его поймать через `except` и напечатать, как это у вас сделано для внешнего исключения. Может у вас там вообще ошибка синтаксиса ))  Хотя скорее всего там что-то с видимостью переменных.